# Why inline functions including asm volatile should be static?

Tags: assembly

For example:

```
static __inline int test_smulwt(int x, int y)
{
    int ret;
    __asm__("smulwt ret, x, y");

    return ret;
}
```

Without declaration "static", there will be compile error "ARM register expected -- `smulwt ret,x,y'". Why?

Thanks,
Simmis.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  If gcc, what about using: `__asm__("smulwt %[ret], %[x], %[y]" : [ret] "=r" (ret) : [x] "r" (x), [y] "r" (y));`

Comment: As to 'why', well, I'm no ARM expert, but perhaps smulwt requires 3 registers, and without static, one of ret, x, y is not a register (memory location? constant?).

Comment: Are you writing in C++? If so, `this` is your culprit pushing `y` to the stack (as David mentioned).

Comment: Thank you, David. I am using uclinux gcc, your suggestion works!

Comment: To Alexis: I am wring c code.